# select hierarchical level data using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table which have following 5 columns:

Zone, Region, Area, Territory, Town

The Region is dependent upon Zone, The area is dependent upon region,The territory is dependent upon area and Town is dependent upon Territory.

I have 5 dropdowns on my page for all those 5 columns.

The user can select the Zone then all remaining 4 dropdowns will be bound depending upon the selected zone and So on for all dropdowns.

I have selected the complete data once in C# DataTable and trying the LINQ Query to achieve the desired result.

On selected index change event of all dropdowns, I am getting the filtered datatable from a method and then giving the Datasource.

Here is my Code:

```
public DataTable GetFilteredGeographicalHierarchy()
{
    dt_DistributionHierarchy = Session["DistributionHierarchy"] as DataTable;
    DataTable dt_Filtered = new DataTable();

    if (DDL_Zones.Items.Count > 0 && DDL_Regions.Items.Count > 0 && DDL_Area.Items.Count > 0 && DDL_Territory.Items.Count > 0 && DDL_Town.Items.Count > 0)//if the dropdowns are already filled before
    {
        IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
                    from records in dt_DistributionHierarchy.AsEnumerable()
                    where
                    records.Field<string>("ZONE") == (DDL_Zones.SelectedIndex != 0 ? DDL_Zones.SelectedValue.ToString() : records.Field<string>("ZONE"))
                    &&
                    records.Field<string>("REGION") == (DDL_Regions.SelectedIndex != 0 ? DDL_Regions.SelectedValue.ToString() : records.Field<string>("REGION"))
                    &&
                    records.Field<string>("AREA") == (DDL_Area.SelectedIndex != 0 ? DDL_Area.SelectedValue.ToString() : records.Field<string>("AREA"))
                    &&
                    records.Field<string>("TERRITORY") == (DDL_Territory.SelectedIndex != 0 ? DDL_Territory.SelectedValue.ToString() : records.Field<string>("TERRITORY"))
                    &&
                    records.Field<string>("TOWN") == (DDL_Town.SelectedIndex != 0 ? DDL_Town.SelectedValue.ToString() : records.Field<string>("TOWN"))

                    select records;                 


        try { dt_Filtered = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //dt_Filtered = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dt_Filtered = dt_DistributionHierarchy;
    }
    return dt_Filtered;
}
```

The problem is when I select the Region then other 4 dropdowns are binding properly but the region Dropdown have only one item remaininng  after rebinding which was selected.

Also, I can not write separate methods for all dropdowns. I have to achieve the results from this single filteration method.

Kindly help me resolve these Cascading issues.

The Binding of Regions should be dependent upon Selected Zone. when I select any Region then it should return all area unders that Region & Should return all the regions of the selected zone, but it is returning only one region which was selected.

**UPDATE**

Following is the method which I'm calling on the index changed event of all Dropdowns:

```
 public void BindGeographicalHierarchySection()
        {

            DataTable dt_Filtered = new DataTable();
            dt_Filtered = GetFilteredGeographicalHierarchy();
            //Before Binding again, retain the previously selected values to  not to lose the selection
            string zone = DDL_Zones.SelectedValue;
            string region = DDL_Regions.SelectedValue;
            string area = DDL_Area.SelectedValue;
            string Territory = DDL_Territory.SelectedValue;
            string town = DDL_Town.SelectedValue;

            if (dt_Filtered!=null)
            {
                if (dt_Filtered.Rows.Count==0)
                {
                    dt_Filtered = null;
                }
            }
            BindZones(dt_Filtered);
            BindRegion(dt_Filtered);
            BindArea(dt_Filtered);
            BindTerritory(dt_Filtered);
            BindTown(dt_Filtered);

            //After Binding Try to make the selection with the previously selected values if they now exists
            //try
            //{
            //    DDL_Zones.Items.FindByValue(zone).Selected = true;
            //}
            //catch (Exception)
            //{

            //}
            try
            {
                DDL_Regions.ClearSelection();
                DDL_Regions.Items.FindByValue(region).Selected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            try
            {
                DDL_Area.ClearSelection();
                DDL_Area.Items.FindByValue(area).Selected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            try
            {
                DDL_Territory.ClearSelection();
                DDL_Territory.Items.FindByValue(Territory).Selected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            try
            {
                DDL_Town.ClearSelection();
                DDL_Town.Items.FindByValue(town).Selected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }


        }
```

Following are the methods of Binding:

```
public void BindZones(DataTable dt_DistributionHierarchy)
        {
            if (dt_DistributionHierarchy != null)
            {
                string[] columns = { "zone" };
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = dt_DistributionHierarchy.DefaultView.ToTable(true, columns);
                if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    DDL_Zones.ClearSelection();
                    DDL_Zones.Items.FindByValue(dt.Rows[0]["zone"].ToString()).Selected = true;
                }
                else//if more than 1 then rebind
                {

                    DDL_Zones.DataSource = dt;
                    DDL_Zones.DataValueField = "zone";
                    DDL_Zones.DataTextField = "zone";
                    DDL_Zones.DataBind();
                    DDL_Zones.Items.Insert(0, "All");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                DDL_Zones.DataSource = null;              
                DDL_Zones.DataBind();
                DDL_Zones.Items.Insert(0, "All");

            }




        }
        public void BindRegion(DataTable dt_DistributionHierarchy)
        {
            if (dt_DistributionHierarchy != null)
            {

                string[] columns = { "Region" };
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = dt_DistributionHierarchy.DefaultView.ToTable(true, columns);

                    DDL_Regions.DataSource = dt;
                    DDL_Regions.DataValueField = "Region";
                    DDL_Regions.DataTextField = "Region";
                    DDL_Regions.DataBind();
                    DDL_Regions.Items.Insert(0, "All");


            }
            else
            {
                DDL_Regions.DataSource = null;                
                DDL_Regions.DataBind();
                DDL_Regions.Items.Insert(0, "All");
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post the code of binding data to the dropdowns?

Comment: are you using the output of `GetFilteredGeographicalHierarchy()` as the source of your `region` dropdown..?

Comment: @vikscool yes I am using the output of this method for binding all 5 dropdowns

Comment: @SamGhatak see my update

Comment: @AlinaAnjum that's the issue as you have filtered the data using the `region` than all the records that you are getting are of that particular region only and hence the output contains only 1 region. So, instead of a single table for all the records have a separate lookup table for the regions.

Comment: Are you able to reduce the problem to only zones and regions? I.e. one zone that has 2 regions but only displays one? Using sample data here would exclude errors in your used data itself and other dependencies of following ddls.

Comment: @vikscool I know this is the problem. but I want a proper solution in this single method by doing any modification in LINQ query or C# code.

Comment: @Chrᴉz you can provide me the solution by considering those two but actually I want all those cascades resolved.

Comment: Not a full answer in and of itself, but the idea is that when a DDL is changed, all of its ancestors have the appropriate value **selected** (but the DDL is not filtered), whereas all of its descendants have their content **filtered** (and nothing is selected). If you filter the ancestor, then it becomes impossible to ever change your selection. If you automatically select a descendant, then it becomes impossible to ever choose a top-level parent without specifying a particular child.

Answer (score 0):

They data should fill in the drop down in a sequence, If zone is selected then fill the
**REGION => AREA =>TERRITORY=>TOWN** as you already want to do so.

1. For Zone drop down -- List all Zones (You just need to fill this dropdown only once)
2. For child dropdown list use the `GetFilteredGeographicalHierarchy` method to get the data to populate in the further child on the basis of parent selection except the `TOWN`

Let suppose you select the Zone then Fill areas under the selected zone and when you select a zone then fill the area. If you follow the approach then you will be able to get the desired results.

You have to call `GetFilteredGeographicalHierarchy` method each time when you select a dropdown to get the filterdata.

**Note:** If you select Zone descendant then never repopulate zones list again.

> I'm calling on the index changed event of all Dropdowns

You should skip calling method BindZones(dt_Filtered); when SelectedIndexChanged event call for other child dropdown

Comment: What about someone selecting an empty entry in all zone descendent fields? Shouldn't you list all available zones again?

Comment: @Niranjan I am calling the GetFilteredGeographicalHierarchy  method every time the selection is made in any Dropdown. Also, I am not Binding the zone Dropdown again and again although I have a problem with other 4 dropdowns

Comment: @AlinaAnjum: You have BindZones method call in BindGeographicalHierarchySection method.. so whenever selection made then it will also bind the zones dropdown

Comment: @Chrᴉz: It will list all available zone again but in case of asp.net once the control is loaded then it is not required to fill dropdown again if it is loaded once at Page_Load event

Comment: @NiranjanKala please see my BindZones method, it will set the selection only

Comment: @AlinaAnjum:Please share .aspx for the page markup for these dropdowns and let us know that where exactly you are facing issue. You should not set selection explicitly if it is set once.. Just populate the decedent dropdowns and skip clearing the selection